# When updating, is it possible to program an app to delete everything about itself then install the newer version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crash, bridging-header

I had an obj-c project which I later converted to Swift. When the users of the obj-c app try to update it to the Swift version, the screen turns blank and the app gets terminated. However, when the app is uninstalled first and then newer version is installed, there are no crashes. FYI, I use a bridging header in the Swift project which uses some old files. I also use HockeyApp to see crash logs but since app terminated directly from launch, I have no feedback. I'd really appreciate any help and insight on this.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to get the crash report that iOS generates. 3rd party SDKs can only send crashes as long as your app is running. It is impossible for 3rd party SDKs to send such crash reports.

Comment: thanks for your response @Kerni, where can I get that crash report from?

Comment: Found this article: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1747/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

The update process is completely handled by iOS. There is no code you can write that could interact with the update process itself. The code you write for update needs has to run in the app process itself.

So if you have a crashing bug or issue in your app that causes it not to start properly, there is nothing you can do other than getting a crash report from the device and fix the bug in your app.